# Jenkins - Mocha tests running in docker app failing with no info

Tags: node.js, jenkins, docker, mocha.js

I just started using jenkins for continuous integration. For some reason, whenever I run my tests they error out without telling me anything in the jenkins console output. As you can see below, I just get told that the operation failed.

```
sudo docker run -e NODE_ENV=test -e Q_DEBUG=1 --rm=true --link mongo:mongo --link redis:redis -it -P company/myapp:branch npm test

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I know that there's a bug in this build that makes the test fail, so this behavior isn't unexpected, but why does it give me no information about why it failed or any of the test ouput?

Comment: can you run a docker ps before this command and show the output?Also is Jenkins running on host-vm or inside a docker container because docker inside docker requires extra steps.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kMSYNduU
and on a host vm

Comment: hmm can you run docker logs on this container after it dies. There may be more info there.

Comment: weird. docker logs gives no output either.

Comment: Try ```sudo docker run -it -e NODE_ENV=test -e Q_DEBUG=1 --rm=true --link mongo:mongo --link redis:redis -it -P company/myapp:branch bash```

and then ```npm test``` manually outside of jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I just hit the same issue.  Ends up it was 2 problems (http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/install-nodejs-ubuntu-14-04

1. "node" in ubuntu may be an amateur packet radio program.  You need to remove this
2. "apt-get" defaults to installing node v0.10.29.  I needed v0.12.0 for other issues (once I solved the first problem, I was getting weird issues with "util".  Ended up being the node version)

I updated my Dockerfile as follows

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get remove --purge node
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
  wget

RUN wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.0/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf node-v0.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

After making the 2 changes above, mocha ran fine AND printed messages to the terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Try [docker-ci](http://docker-ci.org/), it's very easy and transparent way to do continuous integrations. 
You can see everything that container spits.

You can try something like this:

```
@run
  image    : you_code_image
  name     : you_code_image
  cmd      : mocha test/
  daemon   : false

@run
  image    : you_code_image
  name     : you_code_image
  cmd      : node app.js
  daemon   : true
```

It will run tests first, print everything accordingly, and then will launch you container (if your tests are okay)